# How do I center bootstrap tabs in a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to figure this out for so long and I've finally given up... I've already defined a div and I would like to center some tabs in it, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

**HTML:**

```
<section class="area">
    <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">TAB 1</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">TAB 2</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">TAB 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.area{
    border: 2px solid #9A9A9A;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 70%;
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
}

.nav-tabs {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the `tabs` to just stay in center or be stretched to occupy the complete space

Comment: @RajshekarReddy I just want them to be centered

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your code , you have set width to area `75%` the container width `1170px` , container pull out the `area` div, thats why you got this problem, i just put the `area` div into `container`, please check with the snippet. i have solved your issue.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
.area{
   border: 2px solid #9A9A9A;
   border-radius: 3px;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   height: 70%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: auto;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   text-align:center;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
   float: none;
   display: inline-block !important;
   zoom: 1;
}

.nav-tabs {
   text-align: center;
}
</style>

    <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="area">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">TAB 1</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">TAB 2</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">TAB 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @RajshekarReddy sorry for my english, i just edited my answer

Comment: @JishnuVS Thank you! My tabs are now centered :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put you parent class name before the bootstrap inbuilt classes. May b your css file is not overriding the bootstrap css file.

```
.area .nav-tabs > li {
   float: none;
   display: inline-block;
   zoom: 1;
}

.area .nav-tabs {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
           <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">
                     <center>TAB 1</center>
                   </a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2"><center>TAB 2</center></a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3"><center>TAB 3</center></a></li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to centrally align the tabs you need to add the following:

```
.area .nav {
  text-align:center;
}

.area .nav-tabs>li {
  float: none;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tghLqu24/2/ - fiddle created for you to see it working.